# Load JS Script Synchronously but Timeout after certain wait

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

So I'm trying to load a JS file synchronously as it is needed for some other functionality on my site.

However, I want to limit the possibly load delay of this script if it ever takes more than 250ms (which it occasionally does).

Is there any way to use AJAX to load a script synchronously and if it doesn't complete in 250ms then continue to load the rest of the page?

Update:

```
var scriptURL = 'http://cdn.somesite.com/test.js';
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", scriptURL);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if ((xmlhttp.status == 200) && (xmlhttp.readyState == 4))
    {
    eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
    var completeTime = new Date();
    console.log("Script downloaded in " + completeTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime() + "ms");
    }
};
xmlhttp.send();
var startTime = new Date();
```

Comment: So you need the file but you're ok without it? I am confused. Why not load it asynchronously?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642270/load-a-javascript-file-but-cancel-if-it-takes-too-long

Comment: I tried the above code to fetch the script but is getting an access control allow origin error. Shouldnt I be able to download a public script from any domain?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single threaded. Nothing else can run (not even an abort instruction) until your synchronous load is completed.

In your case it seems natural to use an asynchronous load.